# Python update a dictionary inside of a dictionary {"Hello":{"type":"greeting"}}

Tags: python

I have the code

```py
dictionary = {"Hello":{}}
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(data)
    for (word, tag) in tagged:
        dictionary[word].update({"type":str(tag)})
print(dictionary)
```

BTW the "NNP" and "NPP" are just placeholders.
The code is suppose to print {"Hello":{"type":"NNP"}} and it does if it is just one but if it is added to e.g.{"Hello":{},"Goodbye":{}} it changes both {} to {"type":"NPP"}. I have done evaluation and seen that it does change the "tag" but it changes it for all. e.g. for the first (word, tag) in tagged they are both {"type":"NNP"} then on the second one they change to {"type":"NPP"}. How do I stop it from changing all of the values?

Comment: Don't use the same dict for both values.  It would be easier to explain if you included the actual code that demonstrates the problem, but I'm almost certain you didn't do `dictionary = {"Hello": {}, "Goodbye": {}}` to initialize the dictionary.

Comment: Basically what I have is a list of words that I turn into a dictionary via `dictionary = dict.fromkeys(data, {})`  I then want to update the {} this is how I initialized the dictionary.

Comment: That's what I figured you did.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `update` or even the fact that the dictionaries are nested; the problem is that you only created a single dictionary that's used as every value.

Try the following code:

```
dictionary = {"Hello": {}, "Goodbye": {}}
tagged = [("Hello", "NNP"), ("Goodbye", "NPP")]
for word, tag in tagged:
    dictionary[word].update({"type": tag})
print(dictionary)
# {'Hello': {'type': 'NNP'}, 'Goodbye': {'type': 'NPP'}}

dictionary = dict.fromkeys(["Hello", "Goodbye"], {})
tagged = [("Hello", "NNP"), ("Goodbye", "NPP")]
for word, tag in tagged:
    dictionary[word].update({"type": tag})
print(dictionary)
# {'Hello': {'type': 'NPP'}, 'Goodbye': {'type': 'NPP'}}
```

In the first block, each value is initialized as a different empty dictionary.  When you iterate through and update them, each one is updated individually.

In the second block, each value is intialized as the *same* empty dictionary.  Each time it's updated, it's the same dictionary, so the last update overwrites the earlier ones.

If you have a list of words `data` and you want to create a dictionary of empty dictionaries using the words as keys, do:

```
dictionary = {word: {} for word in data}
```

Using a dict comprehension will cause `{}` to be evaluated once per `word` (hence creating a new dictionary for each one), whereas in the `fromkeys` call there is only one singular dictionary provided as an argument.

Comment: Thanks the `dictionary = {word: {} for word in data}` was the bit that helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Here the best way is to just assign:

```
for (word, tag) in tagged:
    dictionary[word]["type"]=str(tag)
    dictionary[word]["OtherType"]=str(tag)
```

After reading your comment, here's the fix:

```
tags=[("Hello",45),("Goodbye",60)]
data=["Hello","Goodbye"]
dic1 = {i:{} for i in data}
for i,j in tags:
    dic1[i]["type"]=j 
    dic1[i]["OtherTYpe"]=j+50
print(dic1)
```

Output:

```
{'Hello': {'type': 45, 'OtherTYpe': 95}, 'Goodbye': {'type': 60, 'OtherTYpe': 110}}
```

Comment: The first approach will fix the problem, but will make it impossible to combine the tag with any other data in the dictionary.  The second approach won't fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks but I want to be able to add more than just "type" into the dictionary

Comment: Use the second method which I posted, There you can use "type" or as many keys as possible. See the edits

Comment: It will still have the same exact problem as OP's original code.  :)  If you can figure out why OP had the original problem, you'll know why your solution doesn't work.

Comment: Note that once the dict initialization problem is fixed, you can just use `update` exactly as OP did; no need to set each key individually!

Comment: @Samwise Now I understood from the commnets, that the initialization was done wrong and that was not mentioned in the question lol :))

Comment: The clue is that OP's code *should* work perfectly well -- the fact that the update is apparently reflected across all the dictionaries at once (in reality a single dictionary) is the clue that `dictionary` didn't actually contain what OP implied it did.  :)